# How is a transaction output's address generated?

Tags: plutus

In Week 6 of PP Lars finds an oracle input with the following code:

```
oracleInput :: TxOut
    oracleInput =
      let
        ins = [ o
              | i <- txInfoInputs info
              , let o = txInInfoResolved i
              -- addr = oracle's address
              , txOutAddress o == addr
              ]
      in
        case ins of
            [o] -> o
            _   -> traceError "expected exactly one oracle input"
```

Does it imply that if a script creates a transaction then transaction outputs will reference the script address through `txOutAddress` field?

Thank you :)

Comment: Here is the code in question: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/36084859defd87c6f13eb166ec64f0d6c6db1242/code/week06/src/Week06/Oracle/Swap.hs#L57

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the question...

First of all, scripts do not "generate transactions", but *validate* transactions. Transactions are *generated* by wallets (and off-chain wallet code).

Now, what *is* the output of a transaction? In the EUTxO-model, it is given by three "things":

- an *address*
- a *value' and
- a *datum*.

The `txOutAddress` function simply extracts the first component of this triple.

So in my example, I am looking for inputs who try to unlock outputs that "sit" at the oracle address. Since the oracle address is a script address, the corresponding oracle validator script will be executed to determine whether the transaction I am looking at is allowed to consume this input.